# Конструктор класса, принимающий в качестве аргументов C-строки

Tags: c++, ооп

Числовой интервал представляет собой последовательность целых чисел, находящихся между заданными нижней (`lowBound`) и верхней (`highBound`) границами включительно. Например, числовой интервал `[2:5]` содержит числа 2, 3, 4, 5. Сам интервал должен хранить только граничные значения, и ни в коем случае не хранить промежуточные.

**header.h**

```
class NumericRange{
private:
    int m_LowBound;
    int m_HighBound;
    bool isValid() const;
public:

    //Объявление конструктора
    NumericRange();
    //Объявление конструктора с аргументами
    NumericRange(int _LowBound, int _HighBound);
    //Через :
    NumericRange(const char * _LH, char _colon = ':', 
                 char _bracketopen = '[', char _bracketclose = ']');

    int getLowBound() const;
    int getHighBound() const;

    void Print(char _colon = ':', char _bracketopen = '[', char _bracketclose = ']');
};

inline int NumericRange::getLowBound() const
{
    return m_LowBound;
}
inline int NumericRange::getHighBound() const
{
    return m_HighBound;
}
```

Конструктор принимает интервал в виде строки, например, `“[2:5]”`. Если передана строка в другом формате, должно генерироваться исключение `std::logic_error` с текстом `"Invalid format"`. Также должно быть проверено соотношение границ как в предыдущем конструкторе.

**header.cpp**

```
NumericRange::NumericRange(const char * _LH, char _colon,
                           char _bracketopen, char _bracketclose)
{
    char colon, bracketopen, bracketclose;
    int nMatched = sscanf_s(_LH, "%c%d%c%d%c", &bracketopen,
                            &m_LowBound, &colon, &m_HighBound,
                            &bracketclose);

    if (nMatched != 5 || bracketopen != _bracketopen || 
        colon != _colon || bracketclose != _bracketclose)
        throw std::logic_error("Error: Invalid format!");

    if (! isValid())
        throw std::logic_error("Low bound higher than high bound !");
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
DECLARE_OOP_TEST(numeric_range_test_string_constructor)
{
    NumericRange r1("[2:5]");
    NumericRange r2("[3:3]");
    NumericRange r3("[-2:4]");

    assert(r1.getLowBound() == 2);
    assert(r1.getHighBound() == 5);

    assert(r2.getLowBound() == 3);
    assert(r2.getHighBound() == 3);

    assert(r3.getLowBound() == -2);
    assert(r3.getHighBound() == 4);
}
```

[image: debug]

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы решили применить ущербную функцию sscanf_s. она хоть и выглядит как обычная sscanf и настойчиво рекомендуется компилятором, но требует больше аргументов. А вот обучить компилятор ругательствам они забыли:)

Читаем в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t6z7bya3.aspx):

> The sscanf_s function reads data from buffer into the location that's given by each argument.
>   sscanf_s Функция считывает данные из buffer в расположение, указанное параметром каждого argument.
>    The arguments after the format string specify pointers to variables that have a type that corresponds to a type specifier in format. Unlike the less secure version sscanf, a buffer size parameter is required when you use the type field characters c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters must be supplied as an additional parameter immediately after each buffer parameter that requires it.

то есть, для каждого параметра типа с нужно приписать сразу и размер буфера. Поэтому, скорее всего нужно написать где то так

```
int nMatched = sscanf_s(_LH, "%c%d%c%d%c", &bracketopen, 1, &m_LowBound,&colon, 1, &m_HighBound, &bracketclose);
```

у меня нет сейчас компилятора от майкрософта, что бы проверить это предположение, но должно работать. Почему работало раньше/в тестах? а кто его знает. Может в параметрах компиляции чего то поменялось (параметр `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS`)

Но лучше выкладывайте полный пример, а не отрывки.

Comment: Спасибо. А каким способом ты бы мне посоветовал решить данную проблему ? 
Данная реализация была мне предложена в методичке нашего руководителя...

Comment: На методички нужно смотреть правильно. Тут лучше спросите своего преподавателя - либо используйте правильные функции (и добавьте правильные опции компилятору), либо не совсем правильные.